# How to display detailed test results on Azure Devops (Builds)?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I created a simple task on Azure Devops, to run Unit Tests on my project.

For that, I'm using the **Visual Studio Test** task and everything works fine.

The "problem" is that, when I navigate to build results and go to **Test Results**, I can only see the failed tests, or in case when all tests succeed, I can't see any.

[image: Displayed test results example]

I'm not sure if it's possible, but ideally I wanted to see all tests results, regardless if they failed or not, so that I can see it more analytical.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's a column that controls that visibility.

[image: Display passed tests]

Comment: Hi @Luiz Soares,

Thanks for sharing your experiences.
I recommend that you can mark your answer as the solution of this topic. This may be very helpful to the people who are looking for a solution for the similar questions.